# Change the url search before user refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my react application I would like for example the current URL is
https://localhost:3000.com?page=10.

Before the user refreshes the page manually, I would like to change the page number to 1 so that it redirects the user back to page 1.

Have tried with `window.onbeforeunload` and adding `eventListener` with `beforeunload` combined with `window.location.search = '?page=5'` (using `setTimeout` works sometimes, most of the time it doesn't).

None of them work.

Comment: Tried with so many solutions, i am beginning to wonder if this is even technically possible?

Comment: Sounds like browsers are preventing you from doing something terrible. You are breaking the user's expectations of what they think will happen. Is there something you are trying to achieve? Maybe you could tell us what you want to happen and we can tell you a different way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express, you could use Express Session, setting a session variable `req.session.sendToOnReload`, then the user reloads the page in the same session it will redirect them to this page.

```
var url = require('url')

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.sendToOnReload === undefined) {
    req.session.sendToOnReload = url.format({
      pathname: req.session.sendToOnReload,
      query: req.query
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.redirect(req.session.sendToOnReload);
  }
}
```

In this code, when the page is first loaded, it sets the page to which the user will be redirected when they reload the page. Then, the second time the user requests the page (by reloading) the server redirects them to the page specified on the first page load.

Comment: What if the page has other dynamic search parameters like sort=price. I want everything to remain the same beside the page number. Would this method be possible for that?

Comment: Absolutely - all you have to do is get req.url and send the user to the new page number by parsing this value. If you can give me an example of a url to redirect from and a url to redirect to I can show you what that code would look like.